# Using a cookie to remove and add classes to list items

Tags: jquery, html, css, list, cookies

I know there are a few posts on this problem but none of them are working for me so I decided to create my own thread.

Here is my list:

```
<nav>
<!-- nav menu -->
    <ul class="clearfix">
        <li><a runat="server" href="Slideshow.aspx">Home</a></li>
        <li><a runat="server" class="active" href="AboutUs.aspx">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a runat="server" href="Contact.aspx">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

And the CSS:

```
nav li a.active
{
    border-bottom: 3px solid #fd9625;
}
```

When the user click on a list item, the bottom border is shown.
I know this should be changed server-side using cookies but I can't get any solution to work for me.

This is my jQuery so far:

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
    $('.clearfix').on('click', 'li a', function () {
        $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});
```

I'm not sure how to implement the cookie.

Comment: What do you intent to save in cookie?

Comment: Cookie? First of all, you can actually read/write cookies on the client side. But - I'm not sure this is what you're looking for. The only *possible* reason you might use a cookie is to save page state - so you have certain sections of a site which will consistently show in the same order.

Comment: I want to use the cookie to set the CSS of the link that was clicked (server-side). The contents of the cookie is unknown to me. I'm hoping someone else could inform me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example -> **http://jsfiddle.net/k6r86/** using [cookies.js](http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Cookies.js/0.3.1/cookies.js) :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var index = Cookies.get('active');
    $('.clearfix').find('a').removeClass('active');
    $(".clearfix").find('a').eq(index).addClass('active');
    $('.clearfix').on('click', 'li a', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.clearfix').find('a').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        Cookies.set('active', $('.clearfix a').index(this));
    });
});
```

See the fiddle, click around and then update the fiddle again and see it had stored the active `<li>` and sets that `<li>`'s class to `active` on reload. I have disabled the links, not an error, simply for test.

Comment: Nailed it! :) Although when I click on my links I am not being redirected. I just removed the `e.preventDefault();` and now it's working 100%. Thanks to everyone that helped!

Comment: Is there a way to set the 'Home' link to have the CSS pre-enabled when the page loads and then have the page continue to give the same effect as in the fiddle?

Comment: You mean, set "Home" as active if active is not set as cookie? Add this line after `var index = Cookie.get...` -> `index = (typeof index == 'number') ? index : 0;` see fiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/VJ52U/

Comment: Yes! :) Just like that! Thank you

Comment: Hi there, apologies to opening an old thread. But how can this be changed so it remembers all the links that has been clicked, then adds the 'active' class. I would like a style on all links that have previously been clicked!

Answer (score 1):

the jQuery Cookie plugin is one way to go:

https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

example: to set a cookie

```
$.cookie('cookie_name', 'value'); // to set

$.cookie('cookie_name'); // to get
```

Answer (score 0):

You need some server side language like ruby or php to achieve this. When the user clicks on the link, you have to do an ajax call to the server, and set the cookie. When the user reloads the page, you have to render your HTML and decide, if the cookie is set, add the proper css class, else, add nothing.

What language do you use server side?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I understand what you mean but I'm not sure how to implement this method. I am currently using JavaScript for server-side.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way using [jQuery.cookie()](http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.4.0/jquery.cookie.min.js) library:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var activePage = $.cookie('page'); // read the value
  if(activePage.length > 0 && activePage != undefined){ // check if it holds any value
    $('.active').removeClass('active'); // remove the existing active class
    $('.clearfix').find('[href*="'+ activePage  +'"]').addClass('active');
  }// add the active class to the anchor which holds the href value
  $('.clearfix').on('click', 'li a', function (e) {
      $('.active').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
      $.cookie('page', $(this).attr('href').split('.')[0]); // save the href in cookie
  });
});
```

#### [A demo with jQuery.cookie() library](http://jsfiddle.net/9YFV3/)

Comment: This does not work because the page is being reloaded each time a link is being clicked on, so the page, and all its contents, are being reset to their default values.

Comment: @PierreNortje yes i agree you can do this way with cookies as i suggested with updated code.