# how to active parent ul li after page refresh or click on sub menu link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, menu

how do i keep selected tab active after page reload or refresh i have working on drop line navigation menu

function is working fine for parent ul li and also parent active when click on parent link 
but problem is that when i click on sub menu link and redirect to another page then clicked parent ul li didn't active and every-time `Home Tab` active or highlight whenever page refresh or redirect to another page

**for example i want like this**

```
 Account Menu is parent menu and child menu like user profile and user accounts
 when i click user profile or user accounts script should active or highlight 
 Account Menu Tab Not Home Tab
```

**Here Javascript**

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$(function () {

        $("li:first-child").addClass("active");
        $('li').click(function () {
            $('.secondary li').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
        });
    })
    });//]]>  

</script>
```

**Html Code**

```
<div role="navigation" id="navPrimary">
<ul class="secondary">
<li ><a href="#">Home</a></li>

<li><a href="#">Account Menu</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">OVERVIEW</a></li>
<li><a href="#">EDIT&nbsp;PROFILE</a></li>
<li><a href="#">MANAGE&nbsp;EMAILS</a></li>
<li><a href="#">EDIT&nbsp;PASSWORD</a></li>
<li><a href="#">CREDIT&nbsp;CARDS</a></li>
<li><a href="#">BANK&nbsp;ACCOUNTS</a></li>
<li><a href="#">CLOSE&nbsp;ACCOUNT</a></li>
<li><a href="#">LOGOUT</a></li>
</ul>
</li>

<li><a href="#">Payments Menu</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">OVERVIEW</a></li>
<li><a href="#">EDIT&nbsp;PROFILE</a></li>
<li><a href="#">MANAGE&nbsp;EMAILS</a></li>
<li><a href="#">EDIT&nbsp;PASSWORD</a></li>
<li><a href="#">CREDIT&nbsp;CARDS</a></li>
<li><a href="#">BANK&nbsp;ACCOUNTS</a></li>
<li><a href="#">CLOSE&nbsp;ACCOUNT</a></li>
<li><a href="#">LOGOUT</a></li>
</ul>

</li>
<li><a href="#">Request Money</a>

<ul>
<li><a href="">Manage Invoices</a></li>
<li><a href="" >Request Money</a></li>
<li><a href="" >Create Invoice</a></li>
<li><a href="" >Invoice Settings</a></li>
</ul>

</li>
<li><a href="#" >Merchant Services</a></li>
<li><a href="#" >Products &amp; Services</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**Updated Javascript but not working**

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
window.onload=function(){
$(document).ready(function () {
    var index = Cookies.get('active');
    $('.secondary').find('a').removeClass('active');
    $(".secondary").find('a').eq(index).addClass('active');
    $('.secondary').on('click', 'li a', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.secondary').find('a').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        Cookies.set('active', $('.clearfix a').index(this));
    });
});
}//]]>  

</script>
```

Comment: you'll need html5 local storage, haha

Comment: @DanielCheung What's so funny?

Comment: @MelanciaUK you got what exactly i want please help thank you

Comment: Not being funny... You will need to keep the selected value somewhere, using a cookie or local storage in modern browsers.

Comment: @MelanciaUK but what should i do ??? im new user of jquery pls help

Comment: @FarhanDharsi You can try http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp, but it's not that recommended because many browsers don't support it. It is hard to do something using only JS, because it is really a temp thing in a page. Or you can try cookie

Answer (score 1):

You will definitely store somewhere the data, wich was the last active tab. If you want to do this on client side only, one solution can be the cookies. See here: [How do I set/unset cookie with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458724/how-to-set-unset-cookie-with-jquery)

If you are using HTML5, then you can use web storage. [See here.](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

If you are rendering your page by PHP, you can use `$_SESSION` variable for this. When user clicks a tab, you make an ajax request, and store the value of the active tab in a $_SESSION variable, but as i see, you want to do it on the client side.

**UPDATE**
Ok, i just created it for you.

First thing is to set an id for every a element in my example, to know, wich is that. You can do it some other way, but now this is the most simple.

Second is to download the jquery.cookie.js, and do not use the URL, store it locally.

Third, here could be a problem, if cookies are disabled on the client machine.

You need to do something like this:

**HTML**

```
<div role="navigation" id="navPrimary">
    <ul class="secondary">
        <li><a href="#" id="home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="account">Account Menu</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" id="overview">OVERVIEW</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

.active {font-weight: bold; color: #F00}

**JQUERY**

ok, stacoverflow does not allow me to paste here a code but i loaded here the 
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/master/src/jquery.cookie.js script also!

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(function() {
        //$.removeCookie("active");
        var activeMenu = $.cookie("active");
        console.log(activeMenu);
        if (typeof activeMenu === 'undefined') {
            $("#home").addClass("active");
        } else {
            $('#' + activeMenu).addClass('active');
        }
        $('li a').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var listItems = $("#navPrimary li a");
            listItems.each(function(idx, li) {
                $(li).removeClass('active');
            });

            $(this).addClass('active');
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            $.cookie("active", id);
        });
    })
</script>
```

Comment: how about this link here i have found solution may be it will work ? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21933575/using-a-cookie-to-remove-and-add-classes-to-list-items

Comment: yes, of course. as i mentioned, you need to download, and load the https://raw.githubusercontent.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/master/src/jquery.cookie.js

Comment: I tried without success, but you can see it here: http://vaso.sma.hu/other/cookie/

Comment: but it should highlight only `account menu` when you click on overview

Comment: ok. but now u see the logic, how the cookies works. just simple add ul li ul li a click, and find the element what you want. now i need to go, please try to figure out, what i did, and search for closest, find, parent, etc... jquery functions, and use them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63034/discussion-between-farhan-dharsi-and-lolka-bolka).